# Ionic 3 - approxItemHeight not working in virtualScroll

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a virtualScroll where I'm specifying approxItemHeight:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="myArray" [approxItemHeight]="'320px'">
    <ion-item *virtualItem="let myItem"></ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The approxItemHeight value seems to be ignored when ionic creates the list.

Here's the ion-list element on page load:

```
<ion-list class="list list-ios virtual-scroll" ng-reflect-virtual-scroll="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-approx-item-height="320px" style="height: 89px;">
```

The style of the whole list is specified as 89px, even though I specified approxItemHeight to be 320px.

Here's the first ion-item element in the list on page load:

```
<ion-item class="item item-block item-ios virtual-position" aria-posinset="2" aria-setsize="2" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 44px, 0px);">
```

After scrolling the list its height is properly calculated, though this is no longer the result of the initial calculation using approx dimensions, at this point the elements have already been initialized and everything is calculated according to their actual rendered size.

The only solution I found so far is to define min-height for the list element via css, though I'm not sure if it's a proper solution and whether or not it'll result in problems in the future.

Can you please help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

By the [Ionic document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/):

> The approximate width and height of each template is used to help
>   determine how many cells should be created, and to help calculate the
>   height of the scrollable area.

We can understand that the approximate width and height is NOT used to fix the size of the item. So if you want to determine the size of each item, just do it in css.

Comment: **and to help calculate the height of the scrollable area.**

Please read my question again. The problem is the calculated list height.

I'm using css regardless to determine the item size for rendering purposes, that's not the issue, the issue is approxItemHeight not being used properly for approx calculations before the rendering happens.

Comment: Sorry, i read your question carfully but still can not understand what is your actual problem.

Comment: List height is not being calculated properly according to approxItemHeight.

Comment: Is you ion-list nested in other element?

Comment: ion-content, but that's how it's supposed to be

Comment: Does your icon-content have attribute `overscroll: auto` or `scroll`?

Comment: I didn't set any attribute in ion-content

Comment: Can you make a plunker to reproduce your problem?